# Map imported Excel columns to Java object attributes

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns, import, import-from-excel

I have a small Java app that parses Excel file (using Apache POI library).
Now I want to map column values to Java object and I'm looking for best solution or pattern for doing this task.

For example, Java object is Customer with two attributes - name and email:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    ... constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Excel file can have many columns, but it contains also two named *name* and *email* that I want to map to my Customer object's attributes in Java.

For example:

- Excel file customers.xls

  [Preview of data from customers.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4L9b.png)

I loop through cells and know that indexes of columns for my Customer object are 0 and 2. I iterate than each row and if cell index is 0 I assign it's value to name and if 2 I assign it to email, but it's really hard-coded and I think there must be simpler solution or some pattern.

Can I put Customer attributes in Enum, then compare them with Excel column names and map in some data struct their order so that if I update Customer object I can easily add another Enum value without hard-coding attributes names in my parsing logic?

Answer (score 1):

I found the exact small project that does perfectly what I want:

[ExcelToObjectMapping-Java](https://github.com/RanjitKaliraj/ExcelToObjectMapping-Java)

After small modifications to source above, I managed to import my excel files and map them to my Java entites.